# Source for Probability of one point in Distribution is zero

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, probability-distributions

I know from my old studies that the probability of one single point, for instance in a normal distribution and quasiprobability distribution, is zero.

**Where should you cite for this fact?**

I have currently very bad cite for the fact, since the book has many mistakes mathematically:

> Redefining a function's formula at the isolated point on the finite
>   interval does not change the function, \cite{howell}, since the value
>   of a function at a single point is irrelevant.

Comment: Probaly like this: **We can redefine the formula at the isolated point because the value at a single point is irrelevant.** by not taking direction about the nature of the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a continuous distribution, like a normal distribution, this is a fact, rather than something you prove. Continuous distributions are, essentially, defined as:

$\mathbb P (a \leq X \leq b) = \int_a^b f(x) \ \textrm{d}x$

so if $a=b$ you integrate over an empty domain, and get 0. Simples.

Comment: Yes, I know this. I am just thinking you did it first so I can cite it. Probably, I should just leave the thing without citation.